# Testing behavior of a mocked S3 bucket using s3fs (by dask) is unexpected

Tags: python, amazon-s3, mocking, python-unittest, dask

I have a simple function which adds a file to a base S3 location. The base location is given as an environment variable:

```
os.environ["TEST_BASE"] = "my-bucket/testing/"
```

The function is:

```
def add_file(file):
    print(f"In function: {os.getenv('TEST_BASE')}")
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    s3.touch(os.getenv('TEST_BASE') + file)
    print("In function: " + str(s3.ls(os.getenv('TEST_BASE'))))
```

Now, I want to test its behavior:

```
with mock_s3():
    with unittest.mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"TEST_BASE": "foo/bar/"}):
        print(f"TEST_BASE = {os.getenv('TEST_BASE')}")

        s3_conn = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2')
        s3_conn.create_bucket(Bucket='foo')
        s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
        s3.touch(os.getenv('TEST_BASE') + 'yoo')
        print(s3.ls(os.getenv("TEST_BASE")))
        add_file('goo')
        print(s3.exists(os.getenv("TEST_BASE") + 'goo'))  # (*)
        print(s3.ls(os.getenv("TEST_BASE")))  # (**)
print(f"TEST_BASE = {os.getenv('TEST_BASE')}")
```

Now, the part I cannot understand is that `(*)` prints `True` *but* `(**)` lists only a single object (`yoo`). What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely what is going on, is that the `s3` object in the `mock_s3` function is caching the directory listing for performance reasons. You create the new empty file with a separate instance, so the outer instance doesn't know that anything has changed. Try inserting `s3.invalidate_cache()` between `add_file` and `s3.ls`.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of `unittest`ing, I ended up with the following `setUp` and `teadDown`:

```
def setUp(self):
        self.mock_s3.start()
        s3_conn = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2')
        s3_conn.create_bucket(Bucket='bucket')
        self.s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

def tearDown(self):
    self.mock_s3.stop()
```

and avoided the usage of the decorator. This is not directly helping in the case described in the question, but, as this use case started the problem for me, I put it here for reference.